# Geodatabase is registered with the server; new feature class is not

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I have an SDE geodatabase with several feature datasets. The geodatabase is registered with the server, and I can publish services without copying the data to the server. I added a new feature dataset, and it is not registered with the server. An ESRI support guy at the UC last year told me that when you add a new feature dataset, it is automatically registered. I have tried adding them as from a database server connection, as a DBO connection. I have tried re-registering the geodatabase, to no avail. Is there any way to register a new feature dataset?

Comment: Just to be clear, you think the new feature dataset and its contents are NOT registered because you've published a map service and the data was copied, not referenced for the resulting service?

Comment: you are probably using a different connection string (admin, data owner, etc) than the one registered with ArcGIS server. the other thing to look at would be the permissions of the data. (clarify if you are using the "feature dataset" term correctly. a feature dataset is not anything that ags can see (it sees data layers or feature classes). A feature dateset is like a folder to hold feature classes.

Comment: There are several different types of 'register': Register as versioned, register as service... it seems you're talking about register as service, not so much registering as versioned. Are you sure that the feature dataset that is registered is the same version? does your login have permissions to 'see' the data - not automatically inherited.